# Preserve Transparent PNG Images on Blogger

Tags: blogger

I would like to post transparent background PNG's on Blogger.

This is the image:

[image: example images]

I have tried to display the image by simply uploading them to Blogger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to host the files somewhere that preserves the transparency.

Start by uploading it manually to [Picasa-web-albums](https://picasaweb.google.com), and then getting the picture URL from there and inserting by URL. If that doesn't work, try other image hosting services, eg Flickr.

Next,  check that there's no template background getting in the way:
If you have a designer template, go in to Template > customize > images, and check if there's a background. if there is, change it to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Blogger supports transparent images. Your template’s background may collide which is why you may not see it as transparent. Change background colour.